# Inverting bit regardless of initial state

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bit

I want to be able to flip a specific bit a 4 bit word regardless of its current state. More specifically, if I have 1111, I want it to change to 0111.

1010 would be 0010. Hoping to do this without an if statement and preferably in Python.

Comment: Show what you have tried please

Comment: hint: assuming you want to flip, xor (^) is the operation you most likely want

Answer (score 2):

It is not very clear from the question, but to invert a bit you **XOR it with 1** (as suggested by [Foon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335398/inverting-bit-regardless-of-initial-state#comment71823417_42335398)).

So if you want to invert only the 4th bit, you need to XOR with `0b1000`, that is 8. Only the fourth bit of 8 is 1 and all others are zero so that will keep other bits as they are, only the fourth bit will be inverted.

```
>>> a = 0b0010
>>> bin(a ^ 8)
'0b1010'
```

You can also make it into a variable which bit will be flipped, by bitshifting one to the left. So if n is the bit we want to invert, then:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> a = 0b0010
>>> bin(a ^ (1 << n - 1))
'0b1010'
```